# Постоение Sequence diagram

Tags: c#, графы

подскажите какой алгоритм на графах следует применить.

Допустим есть исходный код программы, примерной такой:

```
namespace _4lewel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo1();
            Foo2();
            Foo6();
        }

        public static void Foo1()
        {
            Foo2();
        }
        public static void Foo2()
        {
            Foo3();
        }
        public static void Foo3()
        {
            Foo4();
        }
        public static void Foo4()
        {

        }
        public static void Foo6()
        {
            Foo7();
        }
        public static void Foo7()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Изображение диаграмы последовательности и графа построенных вручную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит что необходимо найти в графе три цепи.

```
1) Main->Foo1->Foo2->Foo3->Foo4
2) Main->Foo2->Foo3->Foo4
3) Main->Foo6->Foo7
```

С помощью какого алгоритма это сделать? Перебрать все возможные пути в графе? А потом исключать полные пересечения цепей? Например

Comment: [Топологическая сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Функция может вызывать рекурсивно себя (петля) или друг друга (цикл) - какие пути вы в таком случае построите?

Comment: @tym32167, да тут просто хотя бы найти алгоритм для простых случаев, а не сразу для сложных.